# The correct way to pass the connectionstring from Startup to any other controller

Tags: servicestack, asp.net-core-2.1

I am currently creating a Angular application with servicestack and asp.net core 2.1. I have problem with passing the connectionstring from "Startup" to the "AppHost.Configure" function (AppHost inherits from AppHostBase). What would be the correct way to do this? Should I reload the entire appsettings in AppHost, and then create a singleton in AppHost instead? Or is it some other way which I have not thought of?

I created a singleton in startup, which allows me to access in anywhere else, but not in AppHost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your Connection String is configured as a normal appSetting key, e.g:

```
"MyConnection": "Server=localhost;Database=MyDb;User Id=test;Password=test;"
```

Then when you pass in .NET Core's `IConfiguration` into your ServiceStack AppHost:

```
app.UseServiceStack(new AppHost
{
    AppSettings = new NetCoreAppSettings(Configuration)
});
```

You'll be able to retrieve it as a normal App Setting, e.g:

```
var myConn = AppSettings.GetString("MyConnection");
```

If instead you configure it under the "ConnectionStrings" grouping, e.g:

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
  "DefaultConnection": "Server=localhost;Database=MyDb;User Id=test;Password=test;"
},
```

Then you can either access it from the `IConfiguration` object, e.g:

```
var config = (NetCoreAppSettings) AppSettings;
var myConn = config.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
```

Alternatively you can also access it via the config [hierarchical key notation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-2.2#hierarchical-configuration-data), e.g:

```
var myConn = AppSettings.GetString("ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection");
```

Comment: Thanks! I created a new object of AppSettings for some reason.. The help is really appreciated.